# Adding Input Field to form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/tZPg4/4/)

But it seems that the jQuery version he is using is quite outdated.

However, the only necessary update I see in his code is to change `.live()` to `.on()`. But the remove button refused to work if I changed so.

```
    $('#remScnt').on('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove();
                    i--;
            }
            return false;
    });
```

Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: on() method has been added in jQuery 1.7, you're using the 1.4.3 version

Comment: That may also be because id must be unique!

Comment: @Sam I did notice that :) that code was not written by me.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I did try changing the ID to a class in my local test site, but it didnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The ID must be unique (This is not causing the trouble though)
2. Delegation is needed for newly added content.

---

## jQuery

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('.p_scents');
    var i = $('.p_scents p').length + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" class="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('.p_scents').on('click', '.remScnt', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

## HTML

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div class="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts">
            <input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" />
        </label>
    </p>
</div>
```

This works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/uFkPx/

Comment: @vher2 if `size()` is deprecated, what's the new one? `length()`?

Comment: @HeHui `.length` is not a method; just a property. Therefore, `$('.p_scents p').length` and **not** `$('.p_scents p').length()` is used.

Comment: I'm assuming that would return how many `p` tags exists in `.p_scents` class?

Comment: @HeHui Yup. It will not be restricted to immediate children though!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it needs a rewrite, several deprecated methods, dynamic elements created from strings, targeting all parents(), same ID's etc :

```
$(function () {
    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents'),
        i       = $('#p_scents p').length + 1;

    $('#addScnt').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var p = $('<p />'),
            l = $('<label />', {for: 'inp_'+i}),
            j = $('<input />', {type: 'text', 
                                id: 'inp_'+i, 
                                size: 20,
                                name: 'p_scnt_' + i,
                                placeholder: 'Input Value'
                               }),
            a = $('<a />', {href : '#', 
                            id: 'remScnt_' + i,
                            'class' : 'remScnt',
                            text: 'Remove'
                           });

        p.append(l.append(j), a).appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
    });

    scntDiv.on('click', '.remScnt', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).closest('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/4935/)